# How to pass parameter using JavaScript to MVC Controller - ASP.NET 7

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to do a page redirect using JavaScript in an MVC Core application.  The following function is hitting the correct controller but the `src` parameter is `null` when it gets to the controller but the `nodeID` is not `null`.

```js
$(".jsbnTableRow").click(function () {
        var nodeID = $(this).attr('id');
        var src = "bndlnd";
        window.location.href = "https://localhost:49153/Nodes/Details/" + nodeID + "?" + src
    });
```

The controller `Details` action method looks as follows:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, string src, int? bndlID)
{
    // does stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Url.Action()` to create the required URL with the following syntax:

```cs
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "Nodes")?id=' + nodeID + '&src=' + src;
```

Using an *internal* routing is better approach than hard coded references.